# Limitation of XML file generation in talend

Tags: xml, talend

I want to generate a large XML file in talend open studio (more than 30 000 rows)

Are there any limitations to consider ? Such as size of file or number of lines ?

Comment: 30000 is quite small. Depends on the size of each XML array item. Talend can work with 100’s of 1000’s of records and if you know what you’re doing, millions.